# Why does a change in multiplication sign in factorial to addition sign give such an output?

Tags: python, factorial

Question: Why is the output 11 not 12?
i+4+i+3+i+2 = 1+4+1+3+1+2 = 12

Code:

```
def factorial(n):

    i = 1
    while n >= 1:
        #I changed the signs from * to + after getting the factorial from * method.

        i = i * n --> i = i + n
        n = n - 1
    return i

print factorial(4)

11
```

Comment: You are adding 4, 3, 2, 1 to 1 which is 11

Comment: use `print(i,n)` inside `while` to see values in variables, it can help you to find problem.

Comment: Because `1 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 11` ==> First loop: `1 + 4` Second: `5 + 3` Third: `8 + 2` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get expected `i+4 + i+3 + i+2` and result `12` you need

```
def factorial(n):

    result = 0

    i = 1
    while n > 1:
        result += i + n
        n = n - 1

    return result

print(factorial(4))
```

I add to new variable `result` so I don't change `i` and it is `1` all the time.

I also use `>` instead of `>=` so it ends after `i+2` and it doesn't add `i+1`

Answer (score 0):

```
def factorial(n):

    i = 1
    while n >= 1:
        #I changed the signs from * to + after getting the factorial from * method.
        print(i)
        i = i + n
        n = n - 1
    return i

print(factorial(4))
```

If you print i, you will find i has changed after first loop.
So the output should be 1+4+3+2+1=11

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

Tips from me to solve the problem: 1. understand the concept of loop 2. try to print the answer on your own - i=5, n=3, i=8, n=2, i=10, n=1, i=11